# Angular 5 Deleting object from array in parent component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am new to angular.

I am making a Quote listing website in Angular 5. The child component "Quotes" is where the user interacts while the array I would like to delete form is in app.component.ts. Each quote is an object in an array and I would like the entire object to be deleted when the delete button is clicked but I just get loads of errors.
The current delete button in the "quotes" component html is as follows:

```
<a href (click)="delete(true)">
        <i class="trash icon"></i>
        Delete
      </a>
```

My app.component.ts is as follows:

```
  delete(isComplete,index){
if (isComplete){
    let toDelete=confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${this.quotes[index]}`)

    if(toDelete){
        this.quotes.splice(index,1)
    }
}
}
```

My app.component.html is as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let quote of sortedQuotes(); let i = index" [quote]="quote">
  <app-quote 'deleteQuote($event,i)'>
  </app-quote>
</div>
```

It does not currently work as adding the delete functions broke something.  I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "app-quote". It may happen when the tag has 
already been closed by another tag. For more info see 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have- 
   implied-end-tags (" of sortedQuotes(); let i = index" [quote]="quote">
  <app-quote 'deleteQuote($event,i)'>
  [ERROR ->]</app-quote>
</div>
</div>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@18:6
at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
at DirectiveNormalizer._preparseLoadedTemplate (compiler.js:3220)
at eval (compiler.js:3200)
at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
at DirectiveNormalizer._preParseTemplate (compiler.js:3200)
at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.js:3178)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14908)
at eval (compiler.js:34412)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at eval (compiler.js:34411)
```

Comment: You have a value without an attribute *name*, presumably you're missing a `(click)=`.

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Answer (score 3):

you need EventEmitter that will emit event from your child component

```
<app-quote (delete)='deleteQuote($event,i)'>
</app-quote>
```

child **component.ts** must be like this

```
@Output() delete:EventEmitter<type> = new EventEmitter<type>();

onDeleteButtonClick() {
  //you need to emit event 
  delete.emit();
  // this can be done from button click mostly, which i am guessing is your case
}
```

and you **parent component.ts** will be

```
deleteQuote(event:type,i:type) {
}
```